# Choosing the integral limits for marginal distribution

Tags: probability, integration, limits

I've been trying to understand the following:

> The distribution of two continuous random variables is given by
>   $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{3}{7}x\space\space 1\le x\le 2,0\le y\le x$$and $0$ otherwise. What is the
>   marginal distribution of $Y$ when $0\le y\le 1$?

My question is, how do I choose the limits for the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$$

In the school solution they  did
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{3}{7}xdx=\frac{9}{14}$$

Why are those the limits? What if I wanted to calculate the marginal distribution of $Y$ when $1\le y\le$ 2? Any thumbs rules?

Thanks!